# I would like to know how can I automate my nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to know how can I automate my nested for loops :
for example if x = 2, i'll have this :

```
for i in project['tasks']:
     for j in i['tasks']: 
          whatever...
```

if x = 3, i'll have this :

```
for i in project['tasks']:
     for j in i['tasks']:
          for m in j['tasks']:
                whatever...
```

etc... how can automate this please !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems rather odd to me that you have such a deeply nested `project` variable. It should be clear (and limited) from the start what `project` is, and how many levels it possibly has. If you can limit / set that, you can avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: If you don't know the dimensions ahead of time, or the dimensions are not regular, use a recursive function. An example in the standard library is os.walk(...)

Comment: Of course, in the general case, you could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). But given the above example, it seems to me you should avoid this type of structure altogether.

Comment: do you want a function where you supply the value of `x`?  or you want code that "detects" if current item contains a `'tasks'` member and if so recurses, handles any depth?

Comment: @9769953 yes i know how much levels i have, because my project it's a list of dictionnaries, and in these dictionnaries i have 'tasks' key, that is itself "tasks" a list of dictionnary and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use recursive call, something like this:

```
def myfor(x):
    x -= 1
    for i in project['tasks']:
        if x > 0:
            myfor(x)
        # whatever
        print (x)

x = 3
myfor(x)
```